# to print queried data from fusion table on web page

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I am pretty new to fusion table and google-maps API. I am working on taxi dataset provided by Microsoft.
The data format is of the type

```
taxi_id, timestamp, longitude, latitude
```

The data is collected by roughly 10000 and odd taxis in beijing, over a period of six days. There are separate files representing each taxi's data. As a trial run, i just imported a taxi file on to google fusion table. My idea is, with beijing's latitude longitude as center, and providing an appropriate radius, i draw a circle and engulf all the points with in that circle.

Since i needed to draw circle and engulf points which had only latitude and longitude but not the address ( ST_INTERSECT takes address as one of the parameter i believe), i browsed a bit in google groups and i could make out that i needed to develop KML for the file, instead of uploading direct text file. So i developed a KML where in, i included longitude and latitude within "Point" tag.

so my fusion table consists,

```
timestamp  id  col2 #col2 is a point type consisting of long, lat pair
```

and i could juggle around a bit, and write a javascript to plot a circle and engulf points with in it. The script is as follows.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>csv2kml - Google Fusion Tables</title>
 <style type="text/css">
 html, body, #googft-mapCanvas {
  height: 500px;
  margin: 0;
padding: 0;
 width: 600px;
 }
 #googft-legend{background-color:#fff;border:1px solid #000;font-family:Arial, sans-      serif;font-size:12px;margin:5px;padding:10px 10px 8px;}#googft-legend p{font-weight:bold;margin-top:0;}#googft-legend div{margin-bottom:5px;}.googft-legend-swatch{border:1px solid;float:left;height:12px;margin-right:8px;width:20px;}.googft-legend-range{margin-left:0;}.googft-dot-icon{margin-right:8px;}.googft-paddle-icon{height:24px;left:-8px;margin-right:-8px;position:relative;vertical-align:middle;width:24px;}.googft-legend-source{margin-bottom:0;margin-top:8px;}.googft-legend-source a{color:#666;font-size:11px;}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">    </script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
function initialize() {
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googft-mapCanvas'), {
center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.9100, 116.4000),
zoom: 14,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
map: map,
heatmap: { enabled: false },
query: {
select: "col2",
from: "1D_ZXsYLX20yvYZHBB20_VmSi5haJA5Q65kNML1M",
where: "ST_INTERSECTS(col2, CIRCLE(LATLNG(39.9100, 116.4000), 500))"
},
options: {
styleId: 2,
templateId: 2
}
});
//var lay=layer;
layer.setMap(map);

  //  Create a map circle object to visually show the radius.
    var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.9100, 116.4000),
      radius: 500,
      map: map,
      fillOpacity: 0.2,
      strokeOpacity: 0.5,
      strokeWeight: 1
    });
    // Update the radius when the user makes a selection.
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('radius'),
        'change', function() {
          var meters = parseInt(this.value, 10);
          layer.setOptions({
            query: {
              select: 'col2',
              from: "1D_ZXsYLX20yvYZHBB20_VmSi5haJA5Q65kNML1M",
              where: 'ST_INTERSECTS(col2, ' +
                  'CIRCLE(LATLNG(39.9100, 116.4000), ' + meters + '))'
            }
          });
          circle.setRadius(meters);
        });

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="googft-mapCanvas"></div>
<select id="radius">
      <option value="500">500 meters</option>
      <option value="1000">1000 meters</option>
      <option value="1500">1500 meters</option>
      <option value="2000">2000 meters</option>
      <option value="2500">2500 meters</option>
   </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, i want to print the id's of the points with in that circle on the web page. Note that, the radius of the circle keeps changing as i have given a drop down which means that the text which i am going to display is also going to change. How do i do this? Right now, I have imported one taxi file in the fusion table so the id remains same through out the fusion table. But I will be doing some processing on several taxi files, which might result in merging of tables so the id's will going to be different. Now how do i retrieve the id's of the taxis with in that circle and display it on the webpage?

any suggestions/help are welcome

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 options:

1. Use GViz (query limit: 500 rows) [example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_FusionTables_queryforIdA.html) (using a copy of your table, kind of boring, all the points have the same id)
2. Use the Fusion Tables API v1.0 [example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_FusionTables_queryforIdB.html) (using the same copy of your table as above, all the points have the same id)

[code samples](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/sample_code)